# On the usefulness of uniform convergence

Tags: general-topology

everyone! I've been studying mathematics on my own for quite a while now, and I'm going over Munkres' topology book. When studying the topology induced by a metric there's some emphasis given to the concept of uniform convergence. Now, I understand it's a stronger form of convergence, of course, but right now I'm failing to understand why do we even want such a concept to exist. While I do find it interesting and I'm liking the exercises that use it, I'm in real need to ask here ¿Why is uniform convergence useful other than it being a stronger form of convergence?

Comment: The limit of continuous functions might not be continuous, but if the convergence is uniform, the limit is continuous.

Comment: A simple case is the sequence of functions $f_n:x\mapsto x^n$ on $[0,1].$ They converge pointwise to $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x<1\\1&x=1\end{cases}.$$ Since we like continuity, it is useful to know when a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly.

Comment: Say you are interested in the outcome of an experiment (that is a deterministic function of the parameters of the experiment). It's surely much more convenient to have an estimate of the outcome that is independent of the parameters. That's what uniform convergence is about.

Comment: See [Chapter 7: Uniform Convergence and Applications](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/RV/RV7.pdf) (pp. 117-140) in **Real Variables with Basic Metric Space Topology** by Robert B. Ash (2007).

Comment: Another use for uniform convergence comes when exchanging integrals/derivatives with infinite sums of functions. Physicists/engineers will typically do this with liberty, but you need uniform convergence for this to hold.

Comment: Thanks, everybody! Your answers have been very helful. Thanks Alka and Dave, in particular, because that's something I didn't know.